# How to get one final graph from AnyLogic?

Tags: anylogic

I have an AnyLogic model related to safety in construction. I want to get a graph showing the unsafe behavior versus time. In order to get a confident result, I want to run my model 100 times and thus I will have 100 different versions of my graph. How do I get a final one graph that best represents the results from these 100 graphs?

Is there a method to get the final graph directly from AnyLogic?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a MonteCarlo or ParameterVariation experiment as the first step (so you can run it 100 times).

Then, use a 2D Histogram as in the example model "SIR agent based calibration" (run the MonteCarlo2DHistogram experiment) and draw from a 2DHistogramData object that you fill with data after each run.

There are various things to copy to realize the chart but you can learn it all from that model. Make sure to check the "on simulation end" code section in the experiment properties.

The result looks like below.
[image]